# Dump DDL for EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT - Azure SQL DW

Tags: azure-synapse

If one had used

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT ...
```

to create a file format on Azure SQL Data Warehouse, how would one reverse engineer the DDL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio > Object Explorer > yourDatabase > External File Formats > right-click the external format you are interested in, then click `Script External File Format as...' > CREATE To > New Query Editor Window:

[image: SSMS Scripting]